# ASP.NET MVC ActionLink to Produce the Following HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can I produce following code in ASP.NET MVC with ActionLink (not format throw css)

```
<a href="#"><anotherHtmlElement>Title</anotherHtmlElement></a>
example
<a href="#"><strong>Title</strong></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do it that way? How about

```
 <anotherHtmlElement><a href="#">Title</a></anotherHtmlElement>
```

Also, rather than using `<strong>`, you should be handling your formatting in CSS.

Comment: Why not? E.g. - if `img` tag is supposed to work as a link, it must be surrounded with `a` tag.

Comment: MvcHtmlString automatically encodes the string. It's safer that way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless You introduce new htmlHelper extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use "Url.Content"? Like:

```
 <p>
   Xopto Text <a href="@Url.Content("~/Controller/Action")">in the Controller/Action directory</a>.
 </p>
```